# Is the "once per day" limit on the dream suite a real-time day, or a game day?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

You can update your town in the Dream Suite once per "day" to receive 5,000 Bells. I'm currently time traveling in the past to make up for not playing the game for a while. Will attempting to use the Dream Suite more than once in a real-life 24 hour range get me banned from uploading?

Answer (score 4):

The game uses the system clock to tell the time. If you time travel before you updated your dream town the game will assume that you have not updated it. Likewise, if you time travel 24 hours into the future, it will assume that 24 hours have passed in the real world and you will be able to update your dream.